# Sequelize command doesn't start as second in node script

Tags: node.js, postgresql, npm, sequelize.js

I'm working on tests for Node project and in pretest script want to create Database with Postgres and then run migrations on it.

DB created successfully, but the sequelizer doesn't start. Can't figure out why. Cany ou please point on my mistake somewhere?

My **package.json** test scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "pretest":"nodemon -r esm test/createdb.js && npx sequelize db:migrate --env test",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test mocha --require=esm",
    "post-test":"npx sequelize db:migrate:undo:all --env test"
  },
```

**CreateDb.js script**

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import { Pool, Client } from 'pg';

const PG_DATA = {
    //here is Postgres data
}

export const createTable = async () => {

    try {
        
        const query = {
            text: 'CREATE DATABASE testdb'
        }
        
        const client = new Client(PG_DATA);
        await client.connect();
        await client.query(query);
        return;
        

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }


}

createTable();
```